# Jquery and Drop Down - Determine the Values

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down that I need to compare the values (*the balance*) inside of the drop down and compare this to a global variable, then performing an if / else statement to display some HTML.

Here is the drop down:

```
 <select name="batch">
 <option value='null'>-- None --</option>
 <option value='96'>Check (#2200) (Bal. $84.00) - Jim Jones</option>
 <option value='98'>Credit Card (#0) (Bal. $90.00) - Bailey Adams</option>
 </select>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
    $("select[name=batch]").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() >= GlobalTotal) {
        $("th#show_refund").show();
        $("th#no_show_refund").hide();
    } else {
        $("th#show_refund").hide();
        $("th#no_show_refund").show();
    }
});
```

Is it possible for jquery to ascertain what the balance is inside the HTML select? If so I appreciate a pointer to get me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are constructing this dynamically.  On each option, add an attribute `data-balance=84` or whatever the balance is, then using jQuery, you would use

```
$("select[name=batch] option:selected").attr("data-balance")
```

So, your complete code would be:

```
<select name="batch">
    <option value='null'>-- None --</option>
    <option value='96' data-balance="84.00">Check (#2200) (Bal. $84.00) - Jim Jones</option>
    <option value='98' data-balance="90.00">Credit Card (#0) (Bal. $90.00) - Bailey Adams</option>
</select>

$("select[name=batch]").change(function () {
    if ($("select[name=batch] option:selected").attr("data-balance") >= GlobalTotal) {
        $("th#show_refund").show();
        $("th#no_show_refund").hide();
    } else {
        $("th#show_refund").hide();
        $("th#no_show_refund").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pull that value from the `innerHTML` of the selected value:

```
// Store our Global Total
var gTotal = 87;
// Bind to the change event of our dropdown
$("select[name='batch']").on("change", function(){
  // If we find a dollar amount in our selected element, save it to `amount`
  if ( amount = $(":selected", this).html().match( /\$(\d+\.\d{2})/ ) )
    // If that amount is greater than the Global Total
    amount[1] >= gTotal
      // Do something when it's greater than
      ? console.log( amount[1] + ' is greater than ' + gTotal )
      // Do something else when it's lesser than
      : console.log( amount[1] + ' is less than ' + gTotal ) ;
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/upotuy/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to set your select options' values to the balances, like this:

```
<select name="batch">
    <option value='null'>-- None --</option>
    <option value='84.00'>Check (#2200) (Bal. $84.00) - Jim Jones</option>
    <option value='90.00'>Credit Card (#0) (Bal. $90.00) - Bailey Adams</option>
</select>
```

This lets you get the value without the need for any funky text parsing. E.g.:

```
$("select[name=batch]").change(function () {
    if ($("select[name=batch] option:selected").val() >= GlobalTotal) {
        $("th#show_refund").show();
        $("th#no_show_refund").hide();
    } else {
        $("th#show_refund").hide();
        $("th#no_show_refund").show();
}
```

Comment: hi dan, thanks for the comment, and i totally agree with you. however, unfortunately this drop is created dynamically, so i need to keep the option values as is, as they relate to a database function.

Comment: The above answer from saulce and this approach should get you covered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[name=batch]").change(function () {
 var selectedText= "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            selectedText+= $(this).text() + " ";
          });
```